# How to append element with angular material2 style?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm making a template that if button is clicked then append elements that I want to.
I could append it exactly with following codes but I couldn't add style, angular-material2.
If you have any idea, leave your tip, please.

**make-template.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('tContent') content: ElementRef;

  addTbody() {
    let content = document.getElementById('tContent');
    console.log(this.content.nativeElement);
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.content.nativeElement, 'insertAdjacentHTML', [`beforeend`,
  `
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="file">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="file">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput placeholder="image Info" type="text">
      </mat-input-container>
    </td>
    <td>
      <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput placeholder="image Info" type="text">
      </mat-input-container>
    </td>
  </tr>
`]);
```

}

**make-template.component.html**

```
...
<tbody #tContent>
          // add here
</tbody>
<button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addTbody()">click here</button>
```

Comment: create an array, wrap your tbody with *ngFor="let any of array", if button addTbody clicked, add 1 more data in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic component here to append it-

```
constructor(private compiler: Compiler, public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @ViewChild('tContent')
  tContent: ViewContainerRef;
  cmpRef: any;

ngOnInit() {
  let dom = this.appendDom('<h1>Dynamic Component</h1>');
}

appendDom(template: string) {
     const html = template;
        if (!html) return;

        if (this.cmpRef) {
            this.cmpRef.destroy();
        }
        const compMetadata = new Component({
            template: html
        });

        let factory = this.createComponentFactory(this.compiler, compMetadata);
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
        this.cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, this.vcRef.length, injector);
        const hostView = <EmbeddedViewRef<any>>this.cmpRef.hostView;
        return hostView.rootNodes[0];
}
```

// createComponentFactory Method

```
createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component) {
    @Component(metadata)
    class DynamicComponent {

    };
    @NgModule({
        imports: [CommonModule],
        declarations: [DynamicComponent]
    })
    class DynamicHtmlModule { }
    let moduleWithComponentFactory = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(DynamicHtmlModule);
    return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === DynamicComponent);
}
```

}

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8FGl9UTX8TGdRkw61DB6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use renderer and @Viewchild, and this is not an issue that is linked to your use of material2 but is a basic Angular pattern.

I personally would do this :

```
<tbody #tContent>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        // Your content here
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And in your ts file :

```
items: any[]
addTbody() {
    this.items.push('your new item here')
}
```

So every time the user clicks you call `addTbody` and the `items` array will grow, appending your content to your dom.

You can add styles normally to your html via `class` or `ngClass` or `ngStyle` depending on your needs.

Comment: Well, actually I could append elements with my code. My question was how to add angular material style.

Comment: And my method will have the styles you provide via css

Comment: Hmm... Can you check my code? File input field should be in first row and text input field should be in next row. However, I can't do what I want with your code. I can't follow this code <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        // Your content here
    </tr>